# How to compute the average(or sum) of node values in a network?

Tags: graph, distributed, distributed-computing

Consider a network(graph) of N nodes and each of them is holding a value, how to design a program/algorithm (for each node) that allows each node to compute the average(or sum) of all the node values in the network?

Assumptions are:

1. Direct communication between nodes is constrained by the graph topology, which is not a complete graph. Any other assumptions, if necessary for your algorithm, is allowable. The weakest one I assume is that there's a loop in the graph that contains all the nodes.
2. N is finite.
3. N is suffiently large such that you can't store all the values and then compute its average (or sum). For the same reason, you can't "remember" whose value you've received (thus you can't just redistributing values you've received and add those you've not seen to the buffer and get a result).

(The Tags may not be right since I don't know which field this kind of problems are in, if it's some kind of a general problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an interesting question, here some assumptions I've made, before I present a partial solution:

1. The graph is connected (in case of a directed graph, strongly connected)
2. The nodes only communicate with their direct neighbours
3. It is possible to hold and send the sum of all numbers, this means the sum either won't exceed `long` or you have a data structure sufficiently large, which it won't exceed

I'd go with depth first search. Node `N0` would initiate the algorithm and send it's value + the count to the first neighbour (`N0.1`). `N0.1` would add it's own value + count and forward the message to the next neighbour (`N0.1.1`). In case the message comes back to either `N0` or `N0.1` they just forward it to another neighbour of theirs. (`N0.2` or `N0.1.2`).

The problem now is to know, when to terminate the algorithm. Preferably you want to terminate it as soon as you've reached all nodes, and afterwards just broadcast the final message. In case you know how many nodes there are in the graph, just keep on forwarding it to the next node, until every node will be reached eventually. The last node will know that is had been reached (it can compare the count variable with the number of nodes in the graph) and broadcast the message.

If you don't know how many nodes there are, and it's and undirected graph, than it will be just depth first implementation in a graph. This means, if `N0.1` gets a message from anyone else than `N0.1.1` it will just bounce the message back, as you can't send messages to the parent when performing depth first search. If it is a directed graph and you don't know the number of nodes, well than you either come up with a mathematical model to prove when the algorithm has finished, or you learn the number of nodes.

I've found a paper here, proposing a gossip based algorithm to count the number of nodes in a dynamic network: https://gnunet.org/sites/default/files/Gossipico.pdf maybe that will help. Maybe you can even use it to sum up the nodes.

Comment: Good idea!. I think if we allow the each node to remember whether it has been "visited" and the neighbors to which it has sent msg (i.e. the network is sparsely connected where there're no "super" nodes that have direct links to nearly everybody else), then the DFS would work even without knowing the total number of nodes. Just like traditional DFS, when you can't go deeper, you go up and the algorithm terminates when every Node0 finds that all its neighbors have been visited.